# Firebase sites takes long time to load on every deploy

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

i hosted my react js websites on firebase and it takes a long time to load but after some times it load fast. I deployed again to the same site and the same issue occured. Is it that firebase hosting takes time for the content to fully settle or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Hosting is a static site host with CDN. So the moment you deploy a new version there will be delay to propagate all the new files to the CDNs. Until that the request will have to route to the primary file storage server (Which usually resides in the US). The delay depends on your network speed and the round trip delay to firebase primary server.

Comment: Thanks for this really helpful info. Is there any hosting site that i can use and i won't encounter this issue?

Comment: I am not sure of other Static Site hosts performance, though almost everyone behaves the same. I will suggest you to look for a host that has their servers closest to your preferred location. Check [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/). It seems a good fit.

Comment: What if i use a dynamic hosting platform, would i still face the same issue? or would all my deployment reflect immediately?

Comment: Since its a React app it really doesn't matter if its static host or some dynamic host. Typically you only have a single index.html file and various js & css assets that are required to be downloaded. So it would be better to locate a host (dynamic/static) that is closest to you. But if your application is functioning on a global scale then using a static site host with CDNs will be the best option. Besides the initial propagation delay, the overall performance will be far better.

Comment: Wow. Thanks man. Netlify was the exact solution i needed.